# Why data cannot be deleted in Druid?

Tags: sql, time-series, analytics, druid

We are using Druid as time series database and we have a use case where some data from it needs to be deleted.

I know we cannot run direct delete operation and the technology itself is not designed for that

What are various ways in which this can be possible?

Comment: Why the <sql> tag?

Comment: http://druid.io/docs/latest/tutorials/tutorial-delete-data.html

Comment: SQL because we need instantaneous delete. Not with submitting tasks? Delete should be very similar to insert.

Answer (score 2):

The way this is typically handled is reindexing a segment with itself with a filter.

If you use the ingestSegmentFirehose you can directly reindex data and with the addition of a filter you can eliminate rows.

http://druid.io/docs/latest/ingestion/firehose.html#ingestsegmentfirehose

Answer (score 1):

The way druid stores data and works, doesn't allow it to delete specific rows of data, instead the deletion can be done at segment level. So if you have a way to segment your data which could be deleted in future you could set your fragments accordingly and fire a delete task.

Other way is to use the load rules to not load certain segments or datasets based on some rules, though the data still exist in the deep storage.